# Location of Printer Drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, mdt

We have several networked printers.  When on a new computer, the first printer that gets installed requires admin rights, as it installs some drivers.  After that, any user can open a printer on the network and it installs for just that user without admin rights.

Where can I find these driver files so that I can copy them to use in MDT, so that the drivers are included in the deployment?

Answer (score 2):

To [list *all* drivers](https://www.howtogeek.com/205355/how-to-see-a-list-of-all-installed-windows-drivers/), including locations, to a file in C:\temp, enter the following in CMD:

```
driverquery /v > c:\temp\drvrs.txt
```

Sample output, with some columns removed:

```
Module Name  Display Name           Description              Path                                             Init(bytes)
============ ====================== ======================   ================================================ ===========
1394ohci     1394 OHCI Compliant Ho 1394 OHCI Compliant Ho   C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\1394ohci.sys         4,096      
3ware        3ware                  3ware                    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\3ware.sys            4,096      
ACPI         Microsoft ACPI Driver  Microsoft ACPI Driver    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\ACPI.sys             24,576
```

The only issue is that it is a very verbose listing, and you'll need to search for the printer driver. If you prefer a neater format with GUI, use the free tool from Nirsoft, [InstalledDriverList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_drivers_list.html).

Comment: This does help with something else actually.  But I didn't see them listed after running that.  To test, I ran that before and after clicking the "install drivers" button that pops up when I try to add a networked printer, and it has the exact same amount of drivers.

Comment: It could be that the drivers installed update, i.e., replace, existing drivers. Look for change in version.